# How to calculate false accept and reject rates in pattern recognition?

Tags: self-study, references, pattern-recognition

I am working on a vein pattern recognition project based on SURF algorithm and Euclidean distance. I have completed my program to find the maximum and minimum distance between vein features and find a match exactly when there is an identical image. That is, the max and min distance between two images is zero. In this case, how would I find my false accept rate (FAR) and false reject rate (FRR). Will it be 0% or am I missing a big concept here?

If there is even a slight variation it wouldn't match; in which case, I guess I need to have a threshold value to compare to. I have calculated the max and min distance between all combinations of images with the same hand, and with different hands. In this case, how do I compute the FAR and FRR? This is my first biometrics project and it would be helpful if I am directed to any resource that would help me in this.